# How to Restrict the Drag option of an object within a particular area in ActionScript3

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, draggable

I have two Objects

- one created with scale-factor 0.8 and with height 450 and with width 650.
- And another one created with scale-factor 1.2 and with height 450 and with width 650

When i tried to restrict the drag option of these two objects to a certain rectangle then i found that one object (i.e first one) is moving within the given rectangle boundary but second one is not moving within the rectangle boundary that means it is also moving out side the boundary.

Following are my codes:

```
var rect:Rectangle = new Rectangle(200 , 0 , 800 , Capabilities.screenResolutionY);
obj.startDrag(false , rect);
```

I found that starting x and y co-ordinate point for the both objects are same means these are not moving below x coordinate (i.e 200) but the set width and height of the rectangle is different where i an providing same height and width for the both object.

So i don't know why it is happening like this.

Does anyone have an idea where I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You only have one`obj.startDrag(false , rect);` where is the second `obj2.startDrag`? Is it placed in the same function that you made the `var rect : Rectangle` and `obj.startDrag`. Why use `Capabilities.screenResolutionY` since that's for checking monitor settings??. If your monitor resolution is set to 1200px then **capabilities** is using 1200 as input number. Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes it placed in the same function.

Comment: Sorry I had missed the part about scale factors. Dunno what you can do with it like that. I would have just had like `= new Rectangle(0 , 0 , expectedWidth, expectedHeight);` and if expectedWidth is, for example, 10 times larger than my **obj.width** then use `new Rectangle (0, 0 (obj.width * 10), (obj.height * 20) );`. Try multiplying by the **scale factor** like `obj.width * 0.8` etc if it helps.

Comment: Why `Capabilities.screenResolutionY`?? Maybe you actually want to use  `stage.stageHeight`?

Comment: I wants to keep rectangle height as per screen height.

Comment: But your SWF wont actually fit the entire screen height unelss you go full-screen, even then the `stage.stageHeight` will itself change to become like full screen height (until you exit mode). Anyways if it works for you keep it...